# Grouping in Active Reports 7

Tags: reporting, activereports

When i apply 'keeptogether' property together , group header along with detail section are grouped together , but not group footer which will appear in next page .
I have sub total in group footer . It looks awkward that only subtotal row is first row in next page.

Is there a way by which i can move last detail row to next page also with group footer?

Answer (score 0):

KeepTogether keeps the content within a single section together. However, sounds like you want to keep all of the sections in a group together so try setting the [GroupKeepTogether property](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.GroupHeader~GroupKeepTogether.html) of the GroupHeader to [GroupKeepTogether.All](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/?GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7~GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.GroupKeepTogether.html).

Comment: When i put GroupKeepTogether property to 'all', it takes whole section to next page and leaves first page  with no content but  header only.
I was wondering if its possible to move the last details item (only that) in the page to next page with subtotal

Comment: AFIAK the footer will always try to keep with the last detail unless one of the following are true:

* The last detail section & the footer won't fit on the page. 
* There is only one detail section, and the detail section + Group header + Group footer won't fit on the page.

There might be more varients but those are the ones that come to mind. Are you seeing something else?

Obviously, report header/footer and page header/footer decrease the available area on the page too.

Comment: @d3vil If you want to ensure that there is always at least one detail below a header, set the GroupKeepTogether property to `FirstDetail`. It's in the 2nd link in his answer. *The group header will print with at least the first detail section on the same page or column.*